# generic tap function for XCUIApplication

Tags: ios, ios-ui-automation, xcode-ui-testing

We are trying to migrate from UIAutomation to XCUITests.
For the UIAutomation we came up with a handy 'tapOnName' function which just crawled thru a whole sub element tree and tapped on the element with the first match.

```
function log(msg) {
  UIALogger.logDebug(msg);
}
//recursive function crawling thru an elements hierarchy
//and tapping on the first match of accessibilityIdentifier
//or button text
function tapOnNameWithRoot(name,el) {
  if (el.name()==name && el.isVisible()) {
    log("tap on itt!!!")
    el.tap();
    return true;
  } 
  if (el.toString()=="[object UIAButton]" && el.label()==name) {
    log("tap on Button!!!")
    el.tap();
    return true;
  }
  var elements=el.elements();
  if (elements===null || elements===undefined) {
    log("elements null or undefined for:"+el.toString());
    return false; 
  }
  for(var i=0,len=elements.length ;i<len;i++) {
    if (tapOnNameWithRoot(name,elements[i])) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
var win = UIATarget.localTarget().frontMostApp().mainWindow();
//for ex taps on a button with the text "pushme" in the 
//main UIWindow
tapOnNameWithRoot("pushme",win);
```

No the question : is it possible to implement the same function using XCUIApplication ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is shorthand support for this function in XCTest.

For tapping the first match out of any element, you can get all elements and tap the first one:

```
let app = XCUIApplication()
let element = app.descendentsMatchingType(.Any)["someIdentifier"]
element.tap()
```

If you know what type of element it is going to be, it's better to filter by that type first:

```
let app = XCUIApplication()
let element = app.buttons["someIdentifier"]
element.tap()
```

Comment: The shorthand is very convenient. We named all our UI elements unique so we never have the problem to decide if this is a button, TabBar button etc.

Comment: That's fine, although in terms of speed, it's faster if you filter by type as then there are fewer strings to check for a match with the identifier, and it also makes debugging a bit easier if you run into a problem as you won't need to look through the list of every element. :)

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for something like this:

```
func tapBasedOnAccessibilityIdentifier(elementType elementType: XCUIElementQuery, accessibilityIdentifier: String) {
    var isElementExist = false

    for element in elementType.allElementsBoundByIndex {
        if element.label == accessibilityIdentifier {
            element.tap()
            isElementExist = true
            break
        }
    }

    if !isElementExist {
        XCTFail("Failed to find element")
    }
}
```

where you call the method in the test like:

```
tapBasedOnAccessibilityIdentifier(elementType: app.staticTexts, accessibilityIdentifier: "Accessibility Identifier")
```

You can tweak it a little so that it cover all the requirements.